# how to create a rss feed using class ContentService

Tags: rss, google-apps-script, feed

Is there any tutorial/example which explains how to create a rss feed using class ContentService methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sample creates an RSS feed out of your Gmail inbox (first message in each thread only though).

> **Code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("rss").evaluate().getContent())
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.RSS);
}
```

> **rss.html**

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title><?= "Gmail Feed" ?></title>
  <? var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
     var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
     for (var t in threads) { ?>
     <item>
       <title><?= threads[t].getFirstMessageSubject() ?></title>
       <description><?= messages[t][0].getBody() ?></description> 
       <guid><?= threads[t].getId() ?></guid>
       <pubDate><?= threads[t].getLastMessageDate().toUTCString() ?></pubDate>
     </item>
  <? } ?> 
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 1):

check here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content

```
function doGet() {
  var feed =  UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://xkcd.com/rss.xml').getContentText();
  feed = feed.replace(
    /(&lt;img.*?alt="(.*?)".*?&gt;)/g,
    '$1' + new Array(10).join('&lt;br /&gt;') + '$2');
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(feed)
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.RSS);
}
```